# Скрыть блок конкретному IP адресу

Tags: javascript, json, ip

не знаю, можно ли вообще такое реализовать. В общем мне нужно скрыть блок определённым IP адресам. К примеру блок `<div id="hidden-block-ip">` и я хочу его скрыть для пользователя у которого IP 173.xx.xx.x

Вот что как я это пытался реализовать

```
<script>
var ip = location.host;
if(ip == 176.xx.xx.x) {
$("product-price").addClass("visible");
}
else
{
$("product-price").removeClass("visible");  
}
</script>


<style>
.visible {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Но не сработало. Потом нашёл на просторах интернета такой вариант

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function getip(json){
  if(json.query == "173.xx.xx.xx") {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('product-price');
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';
     }
  }
}
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=getip"></script>
```

Но тоже безрезультатно. Может есть какой то вариант получше, или какие то идеи. Спасибо заранее)

Comment: Во-первых, все проверки внутри скриптов пользователь сможет отключить, если захочет. Во-вторых, что значит безрезультатно? Ошибку какую-то пишет? Адрес неправильно определяется? При отладке на какой строке кода обнаруживается поведение не соответствующее ожидаемому?

Answer (score 1):

В текущей конфигурации Вы получаете ссылку текущего положения страницы.

По своей сути `javascript` не может получить ip-адрес конечного пользователя, однако `javascript` способен создавать запросы `Http`, и уже через них получить нужное значение адреса, поэтому вы можете использовать это как преимущество. Другими словами, если вы хотите получить общедоступный ip-адрес пользователя, вы будете зависеть от запроса на любой сервер.
Вы можете воспользоваться `webRTC` или использовать сторонние ресурсы. 
Подготовил для Вас один пример (Добавил поясняющие комментарии):
В данном случае мы используем API сервиса с сайта `ipify.org`.

```js
    $.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', function(data){ // Получаем через API ip адрес пользователя.
        let div = document.getElementsByClassName('showIP'); // Получаем элемент с классом showIP
        let ip = data.ip; // Получаем ip адрес из data
        div[0].innerText = ip; // Проставляем в первый элемент с классом showIP значение ip адреса
        if(ip == "173.xx.xx.xx") { // Если адрес равен необходимому значению то
            $(".product-price").removeClass("visible"); // скрываем для него данные
        } else {
            $(".product-price").addClass("visible"); // Если адрес другой, то показываем поле.
        }
    });
```

```css
    .visible {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Ваш ip адрес:</div>
<div class="showIP">

</div>
<div class="product-price">Видно ;)</div>
```